# Get groups Cognito Groups using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: amazon-cognito, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I have OpenID Connect setup in my ASP.NET Core app:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>( options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")) 
);
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Cognito").Bind( options );
    });
```

And here's a sample from my config:

```
"Authentication": {
  "Cognito": {
    "ResponseType": "code",
    "MetadataAddress": "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-xxxxx/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "ClientId": "1234",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxx",
    "IncludeErrorDetails": true,
    "RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
    "GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint": true,
    "SaveTokens": true,
    "TokenValidationParameters": {
      "ValidateIssuer": true,
      "NameClaimType": "cognito:username",
      "RoleClaimType": "cognito:groups"
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get `cognito:groups` into my application. However, it seems that it does not come through as an Identity Claim.

Inside one of my pages, I have the following code:

```
var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;
```

When I look at `user.Claims` I see 4 items - `nameidentifier`, `name`, `SecurityTimestamp` and `authenticationmethod`. But nothing to do with `roles` or `cognito:groups`.

Is there a way to expose `congnito:groups` somehow?

Also, I've confirmed that I **do** see the claims in the `OnValidToken` event handler. In fact, `Principle.Identity.Claims` has all 15 of them! It's just that they're not available when accessing the user (in the above code).

Just for reference, here's a sample of my payload:

```
{
  "cognito:groups":["test","test2","test3"],
  "email_verified":true,
  "iss":"...",
  "cognito:username":"fred@test.com.au",
  "nonce":"...",
  "aud":"...",
  "token_use":"id",
  "auth_time":1565837309,
  "exp":1565840909,
  "iat":1565837309,
  "email":"fred@test.com.au"
}
```

Comment: You will probably have to adjust your *scopes* in order for that authentication provider to give you the claims you need. It does not look like you’re specifying any scope. So at the very least, you probably want `scope=openid profile`.

Comment: Thanks. “openid” and “profile” are set by default. So I didn’t need to add those. The other scopes for Cognito are “email”, “phone” and “aws.cognito.signin.user.admin”. Non of those seem to set “cognito.groups”

Comment: can you please decode the token using online tool like jwt.io to confirm there is  cognito:groups claims in the token /

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that there is a `cognito:groups` claim in the payload - with the data I'm after

Comment: see below codes to manually add claim to  principle  and check whether it helps in your scenario .

Answer (score 3):

You can configure `OpenIdConnect` authentication middleware to use `cognito:groups` as a role claim. To do this. you should set `OpenIdConnectOptions.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType` to 'cognito:groups' claims:

```
{
    ........

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
       ........

       RoleClaimType = "cognito:groups"
       
       ........
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the required claims to user principle in `OnTokenValidated` event of `AddOpenIdConnect` extension.

In your MVC client , modify the OIDC configuration to add the event , decode/read the claims from token and add to principle  :

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    ........

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {

        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {

            //find by the claims in token ,for example , if type is groups
            var groups = ctx.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "groups")?.Value;

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("groups", groups)
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },

    };
});
```

Then in your action , you can get the value by :

```
var groups= User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "groups")?.Value;
```

With `using System.Linq;` for `FirstOrDefault` Linq operation .

Comment: Unless you explicitly disable claim mappings, all claims of the incoming token should already be transferred to claims on the identity by default. So it’s unlikely that the group claim is within the token.

Comment: So I applied the code above (except I had to use "cognito:groups" instead of "groups"). `appIdentity` is successfully added. However, the field is not available `user.Claims` inside the page

Comment: Also, I should have tagged the page with Blazor - is it possible that it's not working because I'm using asp.net 3 preview?

Comment: Haven't tried the code in .net core 3.0 , will try it later .

Comment: So is there an option I can check - to see if claim mappings are disabled by default?

Comment: I created a similar setup using ASP.NET Core 2.1 (with the `OnTokenValidated` code above). The same thing happens. When I break on `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))` - `User` has only 1 `Identity` and does not include the `cognito:groups` claim. So I'm assuming I'm missing some kind of config?

Comment: `User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "groups")?.Value;` not get value after adding to user principle ?

Comment: If I change the string to "cognito:groups" - yes it does. However, even though the second Identity is created inside `OnTokenValidated` - it does not result in that information being available on the page when I access the `User` object